# save as Excel with VC++

Tags: excel, visual-c++, save

What should be the form of VARIANT and other arguments requested by `Books.SaveAs()`, as given below. The parameters I took from somewhere else, working fine for `Books.Open()`. 
Of course, the long type parameter I took it by chance, and I am not sure if it's important here.
Thank you!

```
COleVariant covTrue((short)TRUE), covFalse((short)FALSE), covOptional((long)DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);
long AccesLong = 1;

p_Exells->books.SaveAs(COleVariant(p_Exells->myFileName), covOptional,covOptional, covOptional, covOptional, covOptional, AccesLong,covOptional,covOptional,covOptional,covOptional);
ASSERT(lpDisp)
```

Comment: What on earth is `p_Excells`?

Comment: p_Excells is a pointer to a class having the Excel objects (application, Wbooks, Books, sheets, sheet, range ...) as members, so that to use it inside a MFC  project.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the point: the solution was OK, i.e. a CString variable (myFileName) modified to the proper required VARIANT by COleVariant function.
It was just because I inserted wrongly not the File name, but the whole path, including the backslash etc.
Thank you anyway!